# Headphone jack stopped working on windows, but it still works in ubuntu

Tags: windows, ubuntu, audio, analog

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my Acer laptop 1 or 2 days ago. Then I started using Windows, and I realized that my headphones not working at once. I tried different headphones from different brands and nothing solved my problem. I also tried to reinstall Windows, which practically couldn't done nothing - just removed all my software and windows folders -

I tried to change settings from alsamixer and everything worked fine - I minimized the speaker percent and maximized headphone percent - which solved my problem temporarily in Ubuntu.

Windows is not recognizing my headphones after I installed Ubuntu. I also updated all packages ( in software updater ). I searched all over the web and tried most of the solutions I can, none of them worked.

How can I resolve this?

Edit: I installed Ubuntu 15.10 and now when I plug headphone, it won't worked but when I boosted it on alsamixer, everything worked fine.

People are saying that ' Ubuntu configured your sound card in a way that windows can't really understand ' what?

And, I can't shut down Ubuntu 15.10 completely. When everything ends, it just stuck. Nothing happens, not even a sound from hdd, CPU..

Comment: dual-boot, or is windows a guest VM?

Comment: Its a legit dual boot. By the way, I used ubuntu and windows on this machine for a long time but last ubuntu installation screwed everything up

Comment: What version of Windows? Obviously the hardware works. Have you reinstalled the audio drivers?

Comment: Yeah i reinstalled official acer audio drivers which is about 400 mb. The hardware is working fine. Im using Windows 8.1, all updates installed.

Comment: Check the audio mixer.  Have you selected the correct default device? Also, the built-in Windows troubleshooter will sometimes do good things; have you tried that?

Comment: It only shows speakers in the audio mixer, there is no hidden devices or disabled devices in there, too. I tried troubleshooter and it couldn't solve the problem too. If you guys know any program that will give you some info about my system, speakers etc... I will definitely check them

Comment: log into windows, uninstall the sound driver and shutdown the PC (not restart). Boot up again and install the sound drivers and check if that solves the problem.

Comment: When you reinstalled windows you probably erased the previous situation creating a fracture between the old computer and the new computer. BTW to really shoutdown I suggest to close the graphical environment, then CTRL-ALT-F1 and after you log to the console to write `sudo shutdnow -h now`. You will have a full shutdown. Alternatively you can use ` sudo halt -p` to poweroff the machine. More abrupt and less gentle `sudo halt -f`.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll try your suggestions when I get my PC back. I gave it to a friend 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, ubuntu can't configure your sound card. Hardware devices relies on device drivers. A device driver is a layer between your hardware and the OS kernel. It is different for every device and every kernel.

Second, there can be several reasons behind this. What I am speculating is that windows is unable to load the drivers.

Windows 8.1 comes with the feature of hybrid shutdown. Which basically logs out the user and hybernate the system.

You can try a full shutdown. Run the cmd as admin and type the following command-

```
shutdown /s /f /t 0
```

Then start the computer and check if the problem still exists.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue and the below procedure worked for me.

In Windows,

- Control panel--> Hardware and Sound
- Sound--> Speakers/head phones---->Advanced
- Advanced---> uncheck "Allow applications to take exclusive control of this device"
- Reboot